# Browser Misreading Document.write()

Tags: javascript, algorithm, google-chrome, browser, document.write

I'm honestly not quite sure if I've titled this question correctly, because I can't identify the issue. Also, keep in mind I still have much to learn about evolutionary algorithms, and am not a master at them by any means.

The code below is that of a simple genetic algorithm, if you even want to call it that. It's missing multiple features of a real, complete genetic algorithm, but it's simply an example for demonstration. All it does is take a string (predetermined by me, in this case) and mutate it, one character at a time, until the string becomes "Hello, world!". Take a look:

```
var source2 = "og834tnUEF*bt"; //random string
var target2 = "Hello, world!";

function fitness(source, target) {
    var fitval = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
        fitval += Math.pow(target.charCodeAt(i) - source.charCodeAt(i), 2);
    } return (fitval);
}

function mutate(source) {
    var charpos = Math.floor(Math.random() * source.length);
    parts = source.split("");
    var temp = String.fromCharCode(source.charCodeAt(charpos) + (Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1));
    parts[charpos] = temp;
    return (parts.join(""));
}

//functions end

var fitval = fitness(source2, target2);
var p = 0;
while(true) {
    p += 1;
    mutant = mutate(source2);
    mutFit = fitness(mutant, target2);
    if (mutFit < fitval) {
        fitval = mutFit;
        source2 = mutant;
        document.write(p + " : " + mutFit + "  :  " + mutant + "<br />");
    } if (fitval === 0) break;
}
```

I don't believe the description of the algorithm matters too much, because I don't have a problem with the code. This line here:

```
document.write(p + " : " + mutFit + "  :  " + mutant + "<br />");
```

seems to be giving me issues. Although a line break is included at the end, the output in the browser groups up every once in a while for no reason. Check out the JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/oaahzsuf/

Notice the output getting bundled up? I've found that the grouping up seems to occur every time a semicolon is mutated, but I don't know what that has to do with anything. Any ideas as to what the issue is? I feel like I'm overlooking something simple, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `console.log` every string you're appending to the output div, then you'll notice that some of them break your `<br>` tags, because they contain HTML characters, like `<`, and `innerHTML` tries to parse the string into HTML (I checked the jsFiddle, where you're using innerHTML).
The same issue happens with `document.write`.

The simplest solution is to append the `<br>` tag on a second concat operation.

**Like this:**

https://jsfiddle.net/oaahzsuf/1/

```
output.innerHTML += (p + " : " + mutFit + "  :  " + mutant);
output.innerHTML += '<br />';
```

**If there's a chance that your string will ever contain a full tag `<>`, then you could do this:**

```
output.innerText += (p + " : " + mutFit + "  :  " + mutant);
output.innerHTML += '<br />';
```

`innerText` threats the string as plain text.

**A third option is using `<pre>` tags around your string:**

https://jsfiddle.net/oaahzsuf/4/

```
output.innerHTML += (p + " : " + mutFit + "  :  <pre>" + mutant + "</pre><br />");
```

**And a fourth option is escaping the string like @Joe pointed out.**

Also, calling `document.getElementById` that many times in a loop might not be the best thing. Just save a reference to your `output` div outside of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your random-character generator is outputting a `<` character!

Perhaps make your character generator behave by only allowing it to create valid characters that would actually be in your output.

---

If you really want these characters anyway, then [escape the html entities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7124052/1253312) like so:

```
function htmlEscape(str) {
    return String(str)
            .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
            .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
            .replace(/'/g, '&#39;')
            .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
            .replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}

...

document.write(p + " : " + htmlEscape(mutFit) + "  :  " + htmlEscape(mutant) + "<br />");
```

---

Additionally, don't use `document.write`.

If you execute your page [after the page has full loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/800010/1253312), then you can append output to the `<body>` element.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  var documentBody = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  //do work
  documentBody.innerHTML += p + " : " + mutFit + "  :  " + mutant + "<br />";
});
```